# Parse strings and objects from value of cell in spreadsheet

Tags: regex, google-apps-script, split, google-sheets

I got spreadsheet including annoying values and struggle to this. Required data is in each cell of column A. Value of a cell is `{"p0":70,"u3":71,"s7110":40},t45,{"t78":60,"s3310":15},p37,p36,{"p29":44,"s8110":95},p85,p14,{"s2710":41},u47`. Number of such values is about 1000. I have to parse these values. I need strings and objects from such values. I can ignore order of parsed value. I cannot parse manually. So I decided to use script.

I tried to parse using "split".

```
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var values = sheet.getRange("A1:A" + sheet.getLastRow()).getValues();
var result = [];
for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++)
{
  result.push(values[i][0].split(","));
}
```

I got `t45,p37,p36,p85,p14,u47` as string. But "split" also splits all objects. For example, `{"p0":70,"u3":71,"s7110":40}` is split to `{"p0":70`, `"u3":71`, `"s7110":40}`. Is there way to solve this?

Sample values are this. Each line is in cell A1, A2, A3, A4, A5.

```
{"p0":70,"u3":71,"s7110":40},t45,{"t78":60,"s3310":15},p37,p36,{"p29":44,"s8110":95},p85,p14,{"s2710":41},u47
s6610,{"t25":70,"u8":43,"p35":86},u85,u74,{"s7710":83},{"p70":70,"u67":84},{"u71":43,"s1210":73},{"u45":84,"s710":15},{"u14":79,"p22":45},p31
u73,u12,{"t51":98,"u57":96},u31,p41,s1110,s6610,p55,{"t57":71,"s7510":83,"u62":17},u73
t50,{"t83":22,"p18":76},{"p47":12,"s8710":18,"u11":35},{"t14":74,"u72":51},{"p74":21,"t77":77},{"u62":84,"s3010":11},p81,u36,p67,{"t79":12,"u2":70,"s6010":98}
{"u54":51,"t31":31},t56,s4110,{"s3110":84,"t25":92,"p80":19},s3210,{"p65":54,"s8510":45},{"t73":78,"s6210":11},{"s2110":98,"p11":16},{"p61":55,"t88":75},p38
```

Thank you so much for your time. And I'm sorry for my immature question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

B1:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXEXTRACT(A1:A5&",",REGEXREPLACE(REGEXREPLACE(A1:A5&",","{.*?}","($0)"),"([A-Za-z]\d+),","($1),")))
```

We are enclosing all objects and strings except the commas `,` with `()` and then extracting them later.

**EDIT:An easier anchor: The `,` commas to split by are NOT followed by  `"`**

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SUBSTITUTE(SPLIT(SUBSTITUTE(A1:A5,","&CHAR(34),""),","),"",","&CHAR(34)))


=ARRAYFORMULA(split(REGEXREPLACE(A1:A5,"(,)([^"&CHAR(34)&"])","$2"),""))
```

Comment: I appreciate for your answer. Your answer gives the solution of my issue. I did not know to use spreadsheet function for this.I upvoted now. BTW, how should I do to accept 2 answers?

Answer (score 1):

You can use RegExp to replace characters with something unique that can be found without affecting anything else.

```
function myFunction() {
  var L,newArray,thisElement;

  var myStrng = '{"p0":70,"u3":71,"s7110":40},t45,{"t78":60,"s3310":15},p37,p36,{"p29":44,"s8110":95},p85,p14,{"s2710":41},u47 \
s6610,{"t25":70,"u8":43,"p35":86},u85,u74,{"s7710":83},{"p70":70,"u67":84},{"u71":43,"s1210":73},{"u45":84,"s710":15},{"u14":79,"p22":45},p31 \
u73,u12,{"t51":98,"u57":96},u31,p41,s1110,s6610,p55,{"t57":71,"s7510":83,"u62":17},u73 \
t50,{"t83":22,"p18":76},{"p47":12,"s8710":18,"u11":35},{"t14":74,"u72":51},{"p74":21,"t77":77},{"u62":84,"s3010":11},p81,u36,p67,{"t79":12,"u2":70,"s6010":98} \
{"u54":51,"t31":31},t56,s4110,{"s3110":84,"t25":92,"p80":19},s3210,{"p65":54,"s8510":45},{"t73":78,"s6210":11},{"s2110":98,"p11":16},{"p61":55,"t88":75},p38';

  var re = new RegExp("\},","g");
  var parsedObj = myStrng.replace(re,"}zq^");//Replace all }, characters with }zq^

  //Logger.log(parsedObj)

  parsedObj = parsedObj.replace(/,\{/g,"zq^{");//Replace all ,{ characters with zq^{

  //Logger.log(parsedObj)
  parsedObj = parsedObj.replace(/\}\{/g,"}zq^{");//Replace all back to back brackets
  parsedObj = parsedObj.replace(/\} \{/g,"}zq^{");//Replace all back to back brackets with a space between

  parsedObj = parsedObj.split("zq^");//split on zq^

  L = parsedObj.length;

  newArray = [];

  for (var i=0;i<L;i++) {
    thisElement = parsedObj[i];
    //Logger.log('thisElement: ' + thisElement)

    if (thisElement.indexOf("{") !== -1) {
      newArray.push(thisElement);
      continue;
    }

    if (thisElement.indexOf(",") !== -1) {
      thisElement = thisElement.split(",");

      for (var j =0;j<thisElement.length;j++) {
        newArray.push(thisElement[j]);
      }
      continue;
    }

    if (thisElement.indexOf(" ") !== -1) {
      thisElement = thisElement.split(" ");

      for (var j =0;j<thisElement.length;j++) {
        newArray.push(thisElement[j]);
      }
      continue;
    }

    newArray.push(thisElement);
  }

  L = newArray.length;

  for (var i=0;i<L;i++) {
    Logger.log(newArray[i])

  }
}
```

Comment: I appreciate for your answer. Your answer gives the solution of my issue. I upvoted now. BTW, how should I do to accept 2 answers?